# Select rows where column contains same data in more than one record

Tags: mysql

There are plenty of questions with similar titles, but I haven't been able to find an answer that doesn't involve group by (GROUP BY x HAVING COUNT(*) > 1), but what I'm looking for is a query that returns all rows ungrouped (in MySQL).

Say I have the following:

```
id  data
1    x
2    y
3    y
4    z
```

What I want the query to return is:

```
2    y
3    y
```

based on the fact that rows 2 and 3 have identical values in the data column.

SELECT * FROM table WHERE [data contains a value that exists in some other row as well]

Comment: So where the data is equal, but the id's aren't?

Comment: why SELECT * FROM table WHERE data = 'y' does not apply to you?

Comment: In this example, yes. But in general where the contents of one column is equal irregardless of the contents of the other columns.

Comment: @JPG: Because I don't know that it is 'y'. It's just an example. What I know is that I want all rows except those where a particular column has a uniqe value.

Comment: so if you have `3y` and `5x` and `1z`you want to have all listed without z ?

Comment: Then please edit your question to put a sample table with a better example.

Comment: @linurb But id is a PK, so it must be unique !?!?

Comment: Yes, id is unique, but that's irrelevant to the problem. In the real table there are plenty of other columns that are not unique. What's interesting is that data (in the example) is not unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
  FROM table1 x 
  JOIN table1 y 
    ON y.id <> x.id      --   ids are NOT equal 
   AND y.data = x.data;  --   but data IS
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8910

This query and fP's above are probably roughly equivalent in terms of performace - but rewrite fP's this way and watch it go...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.id 
  FROM table1 x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT data FROM table1 GROUP BY data HAVING COUNT(0) > 1 ) y
    ON y.data = x.data;
```

Comment: With your first query I had the same result, i.e. had to restart the db server. But your rewrite of fP's query did the trick. Thanks! I just wish I understood what makes the other two problematic.

Answer (score 7):

You have to put it in a subquery

```
select * from table where data in (
    select data from table group by data having count(*) > 1
)
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81528f/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that. It's extremely slow and and the database freezes and must be restarted. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you have no indexes on the table maybe? Especially on column `data`.

Comment: I have. And the subquery is fast enough in itself. Weird.

Comment: Have you checked with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` if the index is really used?

Comment: On the subquery it is, but not on PK. I'm not sure how to interpret that.
PRIMARY - Using where (31 394 rows), DEPENDENT SUBQUERY - Using index

Comment: Thanks to you too, although it didn't work out all the way. I'll try on other tables to see if there's something fishy with the one I'm working on now.